# Is there a way to clear graphql-rate-limit default in-memory stored contexts?

Tags: express, graphql, mocha.js, e2e-testing, apollo-server

I am writing a GraphQL API using [apollo-server-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-express).

I implemented a rate limit for a login query using [graphql-rate-limit](https://github.com/teamplanes/graphql-rate-limit) directive approach. I use client IP to identify the context, using default InMemoryStore provided by package. `window` value is `60s` and `max` value is `10`. The rate limit implementation is working as expected.

But I wrote security e2e tests using Mocha, Chai, and [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request), and rate limit (as expected) always make it go wrong. It happens because I need to execute login queries to get token before every set of tests. But even if I just set a valid token without request to API, it probably will return an error.

In other tests, I just disable rate-limit. But in the case of security it does not makes sense.

Is there a way to clear stored contexts, in order to avoid the issue? For example, create a mutation for this purpose, or pass a value in headers (both just enabled in development/test environment).